# How can I view HTTP headers in Google Chrome?

Tags: http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

Till 9.x, the headers were under the resources in the Developer Tools, but now I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 894, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact version, but Chrome has a tab "Network" with several items and when I click on them I can see the headers on the right in a tab.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> on windows or <kbd>⌥⌘I</kbd> on a mac to bring up the Chrome developer tools.

[image: Chrome developer tools headers tab]

Comment: Got it, thanks! The page had to be reloaded to view the items.

Comment: That's very nice! I used the chrome://view-http-cache/[url] hack but your solution is a lot nicer!

Comment: Also try `chrome://net-internals/`.

Comment: Just to clarify the answer above a bit - when you click on the network tab you see an overview at first on the right side in a table format with a timeline graph.  If you click on an individual file from the list at the left you will then see the tabs shown in the picture above (including the Headers tab).  This is what @Tower meant by "click on them"

Comment: How do you look at the raw data (raw request data)?

Comment: A quick note: the pane to the right won't show up (at least in newer versions of Chrome) until a resource is selected. If you've gotten here an you're not seeing it, try clicking something down below.

Comment: More to note: **if you don't see any resources** - look at tabs area (`All | XHR JS` and etc) and select `All`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Google Chrome in Ubuntu, works on Windows 10 though...

Comment: One more thing is needed: Network is blank at first.  I needed to open up Network, then refresh the page, and then I can see the file to click for headers.

Comment: `chrome://net-internals/` is outdated most of its functionality is removed. so better to use `chrome://net-export/`  to log the network traffic and then to view log file use `https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import`

Answer (score 31):

For me, as of Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m, the Headers info area is a little hidden. To access:

1. While the browser is open, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to access Web Developer tools
2. When opened, click the "Network" option
3. Initially, it is possible the page data is not present/up to date. Refresh the page if necessary
4. Observe the page information appears in the listing. (Also, make sure "All" is selected next to the "Hide data URLs" checkbox)

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap3a5.jpg)

Comment: Following this procedure, also:
 5. Click on the name of the desired resource in the list on the left.
 6. The preview view will appear in a panel to the right of this list. Above, there are some tabs. Click on the "Headers" tab.
 7. Now, there you go!

Comment: Of course this doesn't work anymore.  These guys are as bad a Microsoft about removing things of value.  There used to be a "raw" option.  Now it's gone (or so hidden as to make it essentially gone anyway)

Comment: @SpacemanScott omg tell me about it! no one asked for those silly changes and we still dont get what we asked for lol ;)

Answer (score 25):

My favorite way in Chrome is clicking on a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){function read(url){var r=new XMLHttpRequest();r.open('HEAD',url,false);r.send(null);return r.getAllResponseHeaders();}alert(read(window.location))})();
```

Put this code in your developer console pad.

Source: http://www.danielmiessler.com/blog/a-bookmarklet-that-displays-http-headers

Comment: That doesn't get the *current* headers, but instead the headers for a 2nd request.

Answer (score 21):

I loved the FireFox Header Spy extension so much that i built a HTTP Spy extension for Chrome. I used to use the developer tools too for debugging headers, but now my life is so much better.

Here is a Chrome extension that allows you to view request-, response headers and cookies without any extra clicks right after the page is loaded.

It also handles redirects. It comes with an unobtrusive micro-mode that only shows a hand picked selection of response headers and a normal mode that shows all the information.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-spy/agnoocojkneiphkobpcfoaenhpjnmifb

Enjoy!

Answer (score 12):

You can find the headers option in the Network tab in Developer's console in Chrome:

1. In Chrome press **F12** to open Developer's console.
2. Select the Network tab. This tab gives you the information about the requests fired from the browser.
3. Select a request by clicking on the request name. There you can find the Header information for that request along with some other information like Preview, Response and Timing.

Also, in my version of Chrome **(50.0.2661.102)**, it gives an extension named **LIVE HTTP Headers** which gives information about the request headers for all the HTTP requests.

**update:** added image

[image]

Comment: just in case someone will need it: if 'show overview' is checked, it is listed bellow the overview and might not be visible (happened to me). You can click the icon 'hide overview' or extend developer toolbox

Comment: @Chris22 please take a look at the image in post

Comment: @AngelM. thanks, ok so according to the image, the 'show overview' is not a checkbox, it's an icon.

Answer (score 9):

I know there is an accepted answer but I recommend

> Talend API Tester - REST Client Extension for Chrome.

example:

[image]

Response shows headers in the same way as petition

Answer (score 7):

In Chrome, Right-click on the screen and select inspect

[image]

select the Network Tab

[image]

and then press `Ctrl + R` You can see Name, Header, Response, and other tabs

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To view the request or response HTTP headers in Google Chrome, take the following steps :

1. In Chrome, visit a URL(such as `https://www.google.com`), right click, select Inspect to open the developer tools. 
   [image]
2. Select Network tab.
3. Reload the page, select any HTTP request on the left panel, and the HTTP headers will be displayed on the right panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Version 78.0.3904.87, OS = Windows 7, 64 bit PC

**Steps:**

1. Press F12
2. Select Network Tab
3. Select XHR
4. Under Name --> you can see all the XHR requests made.
5. To view Request Headers of a particular XHR request, click on that request. All details about that XHR request will appear on right hand side.