# JSoup UserAgent, how to set it right?

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to parse the frontpage of facebook with `JSoup` but I always get the HTML Code for mobile devices and not the version for normal browsers(In my case Firefox 5.0).

I'm setting my User Agent like this:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0")
      .get();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I just parsed http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ and it looks like the user Agent is working. Now its even more confusing for me why the site http://www.facebook.com/ returns a different version when using JSoup and my browser. Both are using the same useragent....

I noticed this behaviour on some other sites too now. If you could explain to me what the Issue is I would be more than happy.

Comment: I can't be the only one encountering this issue, or am I ?

Comment: Thank you Markus. Adding user agent only  solved my issue

Answer (score 59):

You might try setting the referrer header as well:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/")
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
      .referrer("http://www.google.com")
      .get();
```

Comment: @Gili I meant the referrer. What is its role in this?

Comment: @silentbang, websites might look for the `Referer` header in order to detect spider bots so if you want to pretend to be a browser you'll need to set that value too. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: I tried this code for 'www.cnn.com', but it still returned mobile version of web content..

Comment: I found that if I set a user-agent as a browser of windows or mac, YouTube will ignore all the mate tags in the html. So I have to remove it to retrieve thumbnails, title, description to preview these pages.

Answer (score 39):

```
Response response= Jsoup.connect(location)
           .ignoreContentType(true)
           .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
           .referrer("http://www.google.com")   
           .timeout(12000) 
           .followRedirects(true)
           .execute();

Document doc = response.parse();
```

**User Agent**

Use the latest User agent. Here's the complete list http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php.

**Timeout**

Also don't forget to add timout, since sometimes it takes more than normal timeout to download the page.

**Referer**

Set the referer as google.

**Follow redirects**

follow redirects to get to the page.

**execute() instead of get()**

Use execute() to get the [Response](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html) object. Which can help you to check for content
type and status codes incase of error.

Later you can parse the response object to obtain the document.

Hosted the [full example on github](https://github.com/metamug/linkpreview/blob/develop/src/main/java/net/metamug/scrapper/util/DownloadManager.java)

Comment: useragentstring.com seems to be broken now.

Comment: Just for clarification, while the exact link in the answer is broken (http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/), the site itself is up (as of the time of writing of this comment): http://www.useragentstring.com/

Comment: Thanks. Updated the link in the answer

Comment: It doesn't work for https://www.masterclass.com. Can you suggest me anything?

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that Facebook is setting (and then expecting) certain cookies in its requests, and considers a header that lacks any to be a bot/mobile user/limited browser/something else.

There's several questions about [handling cookies with JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069288/how-to-manage-cookies-with-jsoup) however you may find it simpler to use HttpUrlConnection or Apache's HttpClient and then passing the result to JSoup.  An excellent writeup on everything you need to know: [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

One useful way to debug the difference between your browser and JSoup is [Chrome's network inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome).  You can add headers from the browser to JSoup one at a time until you get the behavior you expect, then narrow down exactly which headers you need.

Answer (score 1):

I had the 403 problem and setting `.userAgent("Mozilla")` worked for me (so it doesn't need to be super specific to work.