# Extracting a specific text block from a website into Android App

Tags: android, web, web-scraping

I am developing an Android App which has to extract data from a website and the extracted data will be displayed in a text view in the application

After having tried all the possible ways that i found in the googling and Stackoverflow    i am still unable to process the data and now can any one   share if they have done ..

Details
Website: https://www.amrita.edu/campus/bengaluru

In this website i was looking to extract the data of Latest News block and Upcoming Events

Here's the code : I have used JSOUP to extract

```
package out.in;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.Element;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

  public class HtmlExtracterActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


//  url
   static final String URL = "https://www.amrita.edu/campus/bengaluru";
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);


    try {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(getdata());
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("Error");

    }  

 }



  protected String getdata() throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        // get html document structure
        Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect(URL).get();


        // selector query
       *********Need help 
        // check results
        *********Need help
        return result;
    }
```

}

I have given the Internet Permission in the Manifest file 
and

Xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView android:text=" "

android:id="@+id/tv" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I would sincrely Appreciate the needed Help in advance

Comment: Please attach full stacktrace from exception.

Comment: Hi, do you solve the issue??? Can you share the answer?

Comment: Hi, I couldn't solve this any leads highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned the exact problem you are facing. Did you try to see what is being returned at this:

```
Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
```

I am assuming that this might be because of missing User-Agent in the above mentioned code. Please try this and let us know if you still face the error:

> > Response response= Jsoup.connect(location)
> >                .ignoreContentType(true)
> >                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
> >                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
> >                .timeout(12000) 
> >                .followRedirects(true)
> >                .execute();
>
> Document doc = response.parse(); User Agent
>
> Use the latest User agent. Here's the complete list
>   http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/.
>
> Timeout
>
> Also don't forget to add timout, since sometimes it takes more than
>   normal timeout to download the page.
>
> Referer
>
> Set the referer as google.
>
> Follow redirects
>
> follow redirects to get to the page.
>
> execute() instead of get()
>
> Use execute() to get the Response object. Which can help you to check
>   for content type and status codes incase of error.
>
> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20284953/1262177