# how to check Login with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, jsoup

I want to try to check my login program with Jsoup in Android Studio. But Something is wrong. 
At first I'm login with "Connection.Response". and then after login I get information and put it to element. but when i check with "if" it is not working.
How can i check if login was successful? please help me.

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1, b2;
EditText ed1, ed2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String cheak = null;
            Connection.Response response;
            try {
                response = Jsoup.connect("https://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/login/index.php")
                        .data("username", ed1.getText().toString(), "password", ed2.getText().toString())
                        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                        .timeout(1000)
                        .execute();
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/").cookies(response.cookies()).get();
                Elements element = doc.select(".course_subject");
                cheak = element.toString();

                if (cheak != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username and password is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Next.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username and password is NOT correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: *How can i check if login was successful?* for the start, not on main/UI thread

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand your answer. @Selvin

Comment: Does this code works for you in standalone Java application with predefined values for username and password? Also have you tried adding headers for client agent?

Comment: "*i'm sorry but i don't understand your answer*" that wasn't answer but comment. Anyway I am not Android developer but if it is similar to swing in a way that there is only one thread which handles UI update and user events (like pressing a button) then it is not good idea to add to it tasks which may take very long time because it will give user impression that application froze while handling such long task. It is better to delegate such tasks to different thread and then it is done it should update UI.

Comment: Thank you for your explain))) I understand what do you mean. I think i need to create new class for login. and process should be in this class and check it. Am i right @Pshemo

Comment: Yes, that is general idea (although I am not sure how to implement it properly in Android). But that is another problem. Lets get back to ability to login on site. Some sites don't want to handle requests from non-browser clients and if such client will not send `user-agent` header with proper browser name, then it is most likely not using browser so it will not be handled normally. Also `referrer` header could be needed. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581655/jsoup-useragent-how-to-set-it-right

Comment: Thank you very much for your help)) I will check it @Pshemo