# Using jsoup getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out exception

Tags: java, jsoup

Using jsoup getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out exception

```
private static void getNiftyFutureOIReader() {
        String url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=NIFTY&instrument=FUTIDX&type=-&strike=-&expiry=30JAN2020";
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(15*1000).get();
            Element content = doc.getElementById("responseDiv");
            String jsonCont=content.html();
            System.out.println(jsonCont);

                } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

i am using Jsoup to call website url and read its content, Using jsoup getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out exception

```
error log

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:750)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
    at code.test.BankNiftyFutureOIReader.getNiftyFutureOIReader(BankNiftyFutureOIReader.java:19)
    at code.test.BankNiftyFutureOIReader.main(BankNiftyFutureOIReader.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be due to

1. Make sure you are connected to the internet. Try to open same URL in the browser and see if it opens the page.
   or from Your VM able to reach that url simple curl / wget methods
2. Specify more Jsoup connection time out before getting the document as given below.

Ref: https://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out-connect-timed-out-fix/775

Answer (score 3):

Based on this answer, [JSoup UserAgent, how to set it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581655/jsoup-useragent-how-to-set-it-right), maybe try if the website is checking UserAgent or other Headers to verify your're not a bot. I'd expect a "live quotes" webpage to have such counter-measures.

```
Response response= Jsoup.connect("https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=NIFTY&instrument=FUTIDX&type=-&strike=-&expiry=30JAN2020")
       .ignoreContentType(true)
       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
       .referrer("https://www.nseindia.com")   
       .timeout(15_000) 
       .followRedirects(true)
       .execute();
// TODO: verify Response status code here!
Document doc = response.parse();
```