# Joomla 1.7 - blank administator page

Tags: php, joomla

Until few weeks after installing and configuring Joomla, administrator panel stopped working. After going to http://xxx.pl/administrator or .../administrator/index.php there is nothing but blank page.
It's weird, but when I moved all content of configured Joomla to subfolder, let's say "abc" everything was OK. 
I've searched many times on many forums but all answers was like "Try to reinstall it". Is there any other way to fix it?
EDIT: I'll add here what I wrote in comments below.

- Cleaning browser cache changes nothing
- Problem exists on Firefox, Chrome, IE 8-9
- Logs are empty

Really annoying thing is that everything works fine after copying whole Joomla into its subfolder. Maybe re-configurating .htaccess file? If yes, how to redirect all the pages to their copy in its subfolder? I mean:

- example.com => example.com/abc
- example.com/administrator => example.com/abc/administrator
- etc.

Comment: Enable PHP's `error_reporting` and we will help you.

Comment: I enabled error_reporting as E_ALL and changed debug for "1" in configuraton file. Still see blank page instead of login form...

Comment: Any messages in your webserver log?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache

Comment: Problem exists on every browser: Firefox, Chrome, IE even after cleaning cache. That's weird that everything goes fine after running exactly the same copy of Joomla in subfolder of non-responding one..

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the webserver log file and not the joomla log file as this really sounds like a server error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the HTTP status code when you try accessing it?

(If you are unsure how to see this information, please take a look at: [View HTTP headers in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome))

If the status code is 500, add:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of your `/administrator/index.php` and see if any error shows up.

If the error you receive is something else, are you sure your Apache DocumentRoot or your vhost configuration is OK?

Comment: ok, everything works fine now. Notice I asked for that almost 2 years ago :) But yes, as far as I remember, the problem was with not displaying errors. I don't remember what was the error though. But thanks, I can mark your answer as right :)

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the date... my bad.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if PHP is broken. Put a very simple script (e.g. `<?php echo '1'; ?>`) in your document root, navigate to it with a web browser, and observe whether or not PHP is working.
2. What happens if you execute the `index.php` script directly from the command-line? E.g. `$ /path/to/php /path/to/joomla/administrator/index.php` Do you get reasonable output or errors? You might want to redirect the output to a file (e.g. `> test.html`) and navigate to that file in your web browser to see if it contains anything useful.

Comment: 1. PHP is probably not broken, because site is hosted on the one of biggest hosting server in Poland - home.pl
2. I have no output - it looks like at the beginning of administrator/index.php was die() function...

Comment: 1. I'm not suggesting the host is to blame, but there are plenty of things that might have inadvertedly happened in order to cause problems with PHP. 2. So, once you remove the call to die(), it's working?

Comment: You didnt understand me :) It LOOKS like there is a die function. I've just noticed that $app->dispatch(); function crushes all.

Comment: Okey, everyone, I didn't find main cause of problem. I changed my .htaccess file to redirect every page to its copy in subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly started getting a blank page on all the administrator backend login pages on my sites, could not access the admin section when only the day before it was all working, I had changed nothing server side.

Fortunately after a little testing and checking with other browsers (that were working fine) I notice at some point I must have disabled the java script in firefox, once I enabled it again all went back to normal, logging in again was a back to normal, no blank page.

Hope this helps someone with their issue.