# is there any chrome API or DOM API to get the whole HTTP header that browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

is there any chrome API or DOM API to get the whole HTTP header that browser received from the service（as the following snippet)

---

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objPlaceOrderResponse xmlns="https://api.efxnow.com/webservices2.3">
 ......
```

---

and i wana to modify this HTTP header(eg:i would modify the content-type first and then brower handle this http), how can i do it?

thanks very much!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Comment: @NickGarvey: OP question is about API

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event Listener through weRequest API to modify `response headers` or `request headers`.

## Sample Implementation

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(

function (details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i) {
        if (details.responseHeaders[i].name === 'X-Frame-Options') {
            details.responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return {
        responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
    };
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

## References

- [web Request API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)