# Why does my checkboxes looks different on chrome when I accessed it on localhost?

Tags: html, css

When I open my HTML file by double clicking the file then it open in Chrome, there's nothing wrong with it [here](http://prntscr.com/2aayyt) but when I access it with localhost url using Chrome the checkboxes changed like [this](http://prntscr.com/2aaz01) and when I access it with localhost url using Firefox it looks normal. I tried to remove all the CSS and Javascript but it still the same. Anyone knows why? Thanks I've been stressed about it.
Anyway I'm using XAMPP on my local server.

Comment: Hmm it looks like `Ubuntu` checkboxes :)

Comment: can we see your code as well

Comment: If you don't style a checkbox, it will be set to the browsers default style.

Comment: try a css reset or put your full generated html on a jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Satya here is the code http://pastebin.com/jg9XuRtZ

Comment: @Adsy: on the first print screen it looks normal on chrome, but when I use localhost url it looks different on chrome also.

Comment: @Godinall: how do I do CSS reset? anyway I've tried to remove all the CSS and JS but it still the same. And about the code here is the code http://pastebin.com/jg9XuRtZ

Comment: @RahilWazir I'm using Windows on both printscreen.

Comment: @leonardkekang see here for css reset:http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/
 CSS Reset removes the inconsistent styling of HTML elements provided by browsers. The checkbox is adapting useragent style sheet when no custom style is given.

Comment: @Godinall Thanks but it's still the same.

Comment: Thanks for helping guys, it is solved by @Godinall (see the Answers part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Try pressing ctrl+0 on your localhost page, this works for me. It seems auto zooming on localhost.

Comment: no problem mate, glad it worked out for you, mind select mine as answer :) also you can set initial scale to prevent this which I guess you already know

Comment: Oh I barely know that the asker can select the answer, I'm still new on this site. Done mate, and thanks again.

Comment: @leonardkekang only the asker can really tell is the answer is correct solution, isn't it. you are quite welcome mate, SO is really a good place, have more fun

Answer (score -1):

Check if your webserver is adding any headers influencing rendering like `X-UA-Compatible`.

You can do this using Network Tab in Chrome Developer Tools (press F12):
[View HTTP headers in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Can you tell me how to check it?

Comment: Use Chrome developer tools (F12): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Comment: I've got the solution by Godinall and it works. It'solved, anyway thanks for helping.