# How to handle changes in the validation in the Java Scripts in the J2EE applications

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache

How to handle the changes in the validation in java scripts or adding additional validation in the java scripts?

We need to refresh the browser cache to reload the updated java scripts.

Is there any optimized way to handle the reloading automatically and using the cache when it is required.

Comment: Check the header on your JS file. You can configure it so that the client will ask the server if the file needs to be re-downloaded: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9. **EDIT**: This might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Comment: If you're using Apache, I think this is your answer: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html#Implementing_Caching_Scheme_htaccess