# Wordpress admin stuck in https, how to turn it off?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https, httpd.conf

The admin side of my wordpress site is stuck in HTTPS and very slow as a result.
I am trying to set the admin to HTTP.
Here is my setup and what I've tried so far.

- Godaddy VPS with Godaddy SSL certificate
- In wp-config.php  I have: `define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false );`
- Tried installing the [wordpress-https](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-https) plugin. The admin https checkbox is greyed out / disabled.
  Here are the settings on that plugin.
  [image]
- Check httpd.conf and htaccess files for any rewrites - none found.
- Server does have Vernish installed - asked Godaddy support to check for any relevant configs in Varnish. None found.
- I have tried commenting out code in wp-includes/functions.php based on suggestion [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ssl-enabled-by-default-for-loginadmin-how-to-remove?replies=17) (see comment by user joelbair).
- I always flush caches, and sometimes reboot the VPS completely after making changes.

Any suggestions?
Could it be related to SSL signing certificates or how SSL was installed on the server initially?

Answer (score 5):

Was the HTTPS server sending the `Strict-Transport-Security` header?  If so, your browser received instructions to always use HTTPS version of the site. Try opening the HTTP version in another browser, or try clearing your browser cache in an attempt to remove that header's control.

Comment: Tried with a different browser, and the redirect to https still in effect. Where would I check about `Strict-Transport-Security`?

Comment: You can use Google Chrome dev tools to inspect the server's response headers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome.

Comment: So, only url /wp-admin is redirecting to HTTPS but not root url /?  In that case, `Strict-Transport-Security` is a non-issue, because that header affects the entire site.  Check the `.htaccess` file for any rewrite rules on wp-admin urls

Comment: As noted about that was one of the first things I did. Are there any other files that perform rewrites like htaccess? Any way to debug that? The apache logs show that URLs are rewritten but not the origin of those rewrites

Comment: It's hard to say without actually seeing the URL and responses. What's the URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65913/discussion-between-ted-strauss-and-chris).

Comment: The redirect from HTTP to HTTPS happens in WordPress, and not from Apache, because of URL `wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fchicmarie.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`.  All efforts should focus on identifying the culprit in PHP files and unsetting/disabling it.

Answer (score -1):

- Install [WordPress Force HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-https/) plugin.
- Change you're **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** in General Setting to *https://yoursite.domain*
- Clear browser cache

No configuration needed.

Comment: I get stuck on https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-https , so I guest you try another plugins