# The browser only shows the first application results with Flask

Tags: python, flask

When I run the code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get the string **"Hello, world!"** in the chrome browser, but when I change the code:

```
return "Hello, world!"
```

to:

```
return "Hello"
```

The browser also shows the **"Hello, world!"** not the **"Hello"**.

How does that happen?

Comment: Did you restart your server ?

Comment: @RajaSimon flask should reload itself with `debug=True`

Comment: @Jieter Yes it will reload.. if he changes the return string it will reload. I'm thinking why is not reloading...

Comment: Just copied your example and ran it locally, I see flask reload on file change ` * Detected change in '[...]flask-test/app.py', reloading`, and get `Hello` after changing the return value as expected.

Comment: Maybe there're something wrong with my Flask configuration ,but I just follows the Flask tutorial document.

Comment: @jcxu if not worked .. try app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

Comment: try a different browser, if you see the new results on the browser its probably a cache issue. Depending on your browser you should blow away the cache to see the change. If that gives you the results you want look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627324/disable-cache-on-a-specific-page-using-flask

Comment: Yeah, I have tried the chrome and microsoft-edge,the result has no change, I noticed that the console didn't show the HTTP response like`127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2016 11:03:15] "GET /?foo=1 HTTP/1.1" 200`, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the page is cached by your browser? Use `Ctrl + F5` to force reload , or append `?foo=1` to the url to make your browser make a new request to your web app.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have tried the `Ctrl + F5` or  append the `?foo=1` to the url, but the browser also shows the **Hello, world!**

Comment: Hmm, you are using `debug=True`, so I would expect flask to reload the changed file after you edit it. Are you sure you saved it? Do you see flask reloading after you save the file?

Comment: Yes, I see `Restarting with stat, Debugger is active!, Debugger pin code: 334-192-961`

Comment: Do you see every request you make in the console like this: 
`127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2016 11:03:15] "GET /?foo=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: Yes, if I set `app.run()` not the `app.run(debug=True)`the console will show `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`,but if I use `debug=True`, the console shows `Restarting with stat, Debugger is active!, Debugger pin code: 334-192-961`

Comment: Hmm, hard to see what's going wrong, I tried your exact example and it just worked™...

Comment: I just noticed that my console didn't show the HTTP response like you said `127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2016 11:03:15] "GET /?foo=1 HTTP/1.1" 200`, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @jcxu: maybe you are running multiple instances on different ports?