# Gunicorn reload: don't reload everything

Tags: flask, web-applications, plotly, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I'm building a webapp using gunicorn, flask, and plotly's dash.  I'm using guncorns's --reload option which automatically reloads or resets the workers if any code is modified.  I have observed this basically restarts my entire web app.  At the start of my webapp I'm initializing a client connection and cursor to documents inside a mongo db.  Then the webapp starts graphing stuff.  If I modified the HTML of the webapp, I want gunicorn to reload the HTML side of things only, and not reinitialize the mongo db each time.  Is there any way I can avoid reloading everything using gunicorn's reload?  Or maybe some other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn only reloads the Python code. It will not reload your HTML code.

Your HTML code should be read each time a request is made, unless it is using cached version.
Try disabling cache on the page which you are trying to re-load.

These links should point you towards a solution:

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Caching/

https://gist.github.com/arusahni/9434953

[Disable cache on a specific page using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627324/disable-cache-on-a-specific-page-using-flask)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  My first attempt to disable cache didn't help.  Although I feel like i need to study this a bit closer to fully understand how it works, since its a bit confusing to understand how Plotly's Dash works alongside with Flask.