# Cart not adding correct quantity EF 6 MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I know I've asked a lot of questions lately and for that I apologize, I'm in the process of learning the ins and outs of MVC. Anyways, when I select a quantity and hit add to cart it doesn't add the quantity I select, almost like it just grabs a random number and adds it. Here's the code for the view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.DisplayProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products > Necklaces";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Products > Necklaces</h2>
<div id="update-message"></div>
<p class="button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Orders", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="container">
        <div class="scroll">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="scroll">
                    <div class="itemcontainer">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="@item.Id">
                                    <div class="DetailsLink"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id })</div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div id="@item.Id"></div>
                                    <div class="divPrice" id="@item.Price">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
                                    <div class="divImg"><a class="fancybox-thumbs" href="@item.Image.ImagePath" title="@item.Image.AltText" data-fancybox-group="thumb"><img src="@item.Image.ImagePath" alt="@item.Image.AltText" title="@item.Image.AltText" /></a></div>
                                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div class="divQuantity">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity: @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity, new { @id = "quantity", @style = "width:50px;", @class = "formTextBox" })</div>
                                    <div class="divAddToCart">
                                        <p class="button">
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Orders", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "AddToCart" })
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    }
                    <div class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Back To Categories","Categories")</div>
                    <br />
       </div>        
    </div>
}
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-jScroll.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            //$(function () {
            //    $('.scroll').jscroll({
            //        autoTrigger: true
            //    });
                $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                    prevEffect: 'none',
                    nextEffect: 'none',

                    closeBtn: true,
                    arrows: false,
                    nextClick: false
                });
            });
    </script>
}
```

Here's the code for **AddToCart** in my controller:

```
// GET: /Orders/AddToCart/5
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
{
    // Retrieve the product from the database
    var productAdded = db.Products
        .Single(p => p.ProductId == id);

    // Add it to the shopping cart
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

    cart.AddToCart(productAdded);

    // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And finally the code for **AddToCart** in my **ShoppingCart** model:

```
 public void AddToCart(Product item)
    {
        // Get the matching cart and product instances
        var order = entities.Orders.FirstOrDefault(
            c => c.OrderGUID == ShoppingCartId
            && c.OrderItems.Where(p=>p.ProductId == item.ProductId).FirstOrDefault().ProductId == item.ProductId);

        if (order == null)
        {
            // Create a new order since one doesn't already exist
            order = new Order
            {
                InvoiceNumber = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                OrderDate=DateTime.Now,
                OrderGUID = ShoppingCartId,
                IsShipped = false
            };
            entities.Orders.Add(order);

            // Save changes
            entities.SaveChanges();

            //add the OrderItem for the new order
            OrderItem oi = new OrderItem()
            {
                OrderId = order.OrderId,
                OrderGUID = ShoppingCartId,
                ProductId = item.ProductId,
                ProductQuantity = item.Quantity,
                ProductPrice = item.ProductPrice
            };

            entities.OrderItems.Add(oi);
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            // If the item does exist in the cart, 
            // then add one to the quantity
            order.OrderItems.Where(p => p.ProductId == item.ProductId).FirstOrDefault().ProductQuantity++;
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }            
    }
```

Code for **DisplayProductsViewModel**:

using AccessorizeForLess.Data;

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels
{
    public class DisplayProductsViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        public ProductImage Image { get; set; }

        public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can anyone possibly see what I'm doing wrong

**EDIT**

This is what I see when I use the debugging tools

[image]

**EDIT**
'Here is the new view with the submit button added

```
@model IEnumerable<AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.DisplayProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products > Necklaces";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Products > Necklaces</h2>
<div id="update-message"></div>
<p class="button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Orders", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="container">
        <div class="scroll">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="scroll2">
                    <div class="itemcontainer">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="@item.Id">
                                    <div class="DetailsLink"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id })</div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div id="@item.Id"></div>
                                    <div class="divPrice" id="@item.Price">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
                                    <div class="divImg"><a class="fancybox-thumbs" href="@item.Image.ImagePath" title="@item.Image.AltText" data-fancybox-group="thumb"><img src="@item.Image.ImagePath" alt="@item.Image.AltText" title="@item.Image.AltText" /></a></div>
                                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div class="divQuantity">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity: @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity, new { @id = "quantity", @style = "width:50px;", @class = "formTextBox" })</div>
                                    <div class="divAddToCart">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" class="btn btn-default" /> @*@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Orders", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "AddToCart" })*@

                                    </div>
                                    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    }
                    <div class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Back To Categories","Categories")</div>
                    <br />
       </div>        
    </div>
}
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-jScroll.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            //$(function () {
            //    $('.scroll').jscroll({
            //        autoTrigger: true
            //    });
                $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                    prevEffect: 'none',
                    nextEffect: 'none',

                    closeBtn: true,
                    arrows: false,
                    nextClick: false
                });

                // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
                //$(".AddToCart").click(function () {
                //    alert('Clicked!');
                //});
            //s});
    </script>
}
```

And **AddToCart**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(DisplayProductDetailsViewModel model)
{
    // Retrieve the product from the database
    var productAdded = db.Products
        .Single(p => p.ProductId == model.Id);

    // Add it to the shopping cart
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

    cart.AddToCart(productAdded);

    // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in AddToCart model is always null, what am I missing here?

Comment: When you run the debugger on this is `item.Quantity` correct? What does the network request show you for the `POST AddToCart`?

Comment: Also, `GET AddToCart` is cachable by the browser. You should be doing a POST.

Comment: @Jasen **item.Quantity** is always 1 (I stepped through), it's like it's not picking up the value from the textbox in the view

Comment: Ok, now is the network request reflecting what was entered into the form?

Comment: @Jasen no, it doesnt matter what I enter for a quantity it's always 1

Comment: What does the network request -- headers and body-- look like? Open the browser's debugger, use its network monitor, then make your request. What are the details for that request (before it gets to the server)?

Comment: @Jasen I guess I'm semi-stupid because I dont understand what it is you're asking kind sir.

Comment: Open the browser's debugging tools (usually F12). Click network tab. Click  preserve log. Click start recording. Make your AddToCart request. Watch debugger for AddToCart and click on it for details. [Here's a nice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423097/2030565) picture of what you want -- it's for Chrome but FF and IE are very similar.

Comment: @Jasen I did what you suggested and didn't see AddtoCart anywhere in the list

Comment: @Jasen check my edit, I added a picture of what I see when I followed your instructions

Answer (score 0):

You are always sending the same quantity because you always trigger the ActionLink's GET request that only passes the query string parameter `id`. The quantity field in your form is never sent as that's part of the POST form body submission.

```
// you are not triggering this submission: POST AddToCart
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Orders", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // quantity is passed on the request's body
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)

    // but GET AddToCart/id is send instead
    @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Orders", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "AddToCart" })
}
```

As indicated by your screenshot

```
Request URL: http://localhost:24177/Orders/AddToCart/21
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
```

Notice "Form Data" or "Request Body" is missing from your request.

Each time you call `GET AddToCart` you query the same product from the data store and set the quantity property to the same value.

You ought to [send this GET request as POST](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server) instead because:

- It can be cached by the browser and it won't make subsequent requests to the 
  server
- Web crawlers can trigger the ActionLink request

So add a submit button to your form and make a POST action. Then be sure the assign a new quantity from the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(FormModel model)
{
    var product = db.Products.Where(... && p => p.Id == model.ProductId);
    var quantity = model.ProductQuantity;

    cart.AddToCart(product, quantity);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: @Jansen I'm trying to follow where you're going here I really am. I changed the view and made some changes to AddToCart, can you check the latest edit and tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Try a submission without a foreach loop. Then make sure the model property names match your form's input names (verify with the rendered html source).

Comment: All the properties of **model** in **AddToCart** are null, and there isnt even a property for quantity. I checked the rendered HTML and changed all my property naes to match the ids in the view and still nothing.

Comment: Again, does the network request match what you expect at the server? Match up the input `name` attribute rather than the `id` attribute to the model property.

Comment: @Jansen I wanted to come back to this question and thank you for all the help you have offered me in this issue. I wanted you to know how much I appreciate the time you took to teach me things I didn't know but now know. The client has decided to go the AJAX route, but dont think  I dont appreciate you and what you taught me.