# Displaying "traditional chinese" language text on web page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a web page that should display the characters on web page in Chinese language, however currently it is not displaying so: 
Till now, I have implemented below written code, but still not able to fix:

in my header file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

mySql table is being set to:

```
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

The table shows Chinese characters without any fail.
What else needs to be done to show the text on the web page?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" ></meta> add space between two attribute.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. can you please elaborate

Comment: add space after ; in content.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta, that should not matter.  See this link http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset#server

Comment: @user4943236 , can you post the [tag:php] code to generate the [tag:HTML] content?  Can you also post the http response headers used with file response?

Comment: @Eric php code posted. where can I find the http response headers? sorry, i'm a newbie in this

Comment: Your problem is not with chinese characters, but with UTF-8. Read this classic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: See this post on how to view the headers in [tag:chrome], https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

This helped in solving my problem:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```