# android picasso okhttp verify http headers

Tags: php, android, picasso, okhttp

In my gradle dependencies, I've added:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
```

And then I use Picasso normally, for example:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
.error(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
.into(imageView);
```

Now, the url is a php script from which I'm doing `echo file_get_contents("$imagepath");`
The image is being fetched and displayed by picasso.

But before doing echo, I'm also setting some headers like:

```
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $lastModified)." GMT");
header("Etag: $etagFile");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=60');
```

Now, whenever picasso will consult okhttp, will okhttp send these headers with the http request? How can verify whether they are sent?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to that url with Chrome and see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome) for how to inspect HTTP headers in Chrome.

[This website](http://request.urih.com/) will show you the headers sent by an HTTP client. If you're on Linux then [this SO answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/504431/human-readable-format-for-http-headers-with-tcpdump) provides a way to this using TCPDump

Comment: LIke I said, I want test whether the http client (okhttp) really sends back those headers or not. A browser is not helpful here