# Username and password authentication in angular

Tags: angularjs, http

I am trying to deploy a flask+angular app, where flask is hosted on a Digital Ocean ubuntu server.

The api is based on this [guide](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask).

In curl I can confirm it works by: `curl -u <username>:<passwd> -i -X GET https://<server>`

I try to obtain the same in angular using http:

`$http.get('https://<server>', 
{username: <user>, password: <password>})
.then(function(response){
console.log(response.data});`

Results in a 401 UNAUTHORIZED

I hope you can help me here.

Comment: Check the headers that you are sending

Comment: How do I check the headers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Comment: I checked the headers, and they contain username and password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `post` methods instead of `get` to send data

```
$http.post('https://<server>', 
    {username: <user>, password: <password>})
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

and in serve get by `req.body.username`. I assume server side is 'node.js' that's why used 'req.body'.

then also need `post` method in server side to accept your `post` request for your `url`.

**OR**

If you want to use `get` method then you can send data as a `params` like

```
var config = {
 params: {username: <user>, password: <password>},
 headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json'}
};

$http.get('https://<server>', config).then(function(response) {
   // process response here..
   console.log(response.data);
 });
```

Comment: backend is flask, just like this [link](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask)

Comment: for `Flask` get data using `request.json.get('username')`

Comment: but is it not "wrong" to use a post only because of authentication, when I would use a GET without authentication?

Comment: Can use as you need but you can't send data using get method if you want to use get method you should send `data` as  `params` not as data. I updated my answer @DauleDK

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated answer. Is it safe to use params, when using https?

Comment: as far I know the whole URL, and even the type of request (get, post, etc.) is encrypted when using HTTPS. but better to send `token` instead of `username` and `password`