# Odoo V9 Website Cache Issue

Tags: odoo, cache-control, odoo-9, odoo-website

I have certain custom sales order pages on odoo e-commerce website, which are been loaded based on the templates designed. The page loads dynamic data of sales order stored in the session, but it is either loading old data or not requesting to server and just loading the page from the cache. So to do this I have to manually load the page again by refreshing the page to load the current correct data. **This is the problem when I have a domain name assigned for my website, If I access this same website using the IP address it works correctly.** So I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: The caching headers the server is sending may be too generous. When you hit "refresh" in the browser, it disregards those headers and fetches fresh data. That's a good first thing to check out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Comment: @Pekka웃 I tried to visit the url that you suggested.. but actually didn't got idea, what exactly I should do. Please can you guide more?

Comment: I don't know Odoo so I can't really help much - but the caching headers you can look at by opening the page in question, and then following the advice in the linked question above. Navigate to the "response headers" area and look for anything related to caching there (`Cache-control`, `expires`, `If-modified-since`) and post it here (or just dump the whole set of headers if you're not sure what to look for)