# Ajax Post - Unable to get Post variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

codeigniter 2.0

form.tpl:

```
<form class="form-book" id="class-form" method="POST">
  inside full of checkbox....
<button type="button" class="btn" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-btn').click(function(){  
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");
                var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.example.com/booking/checkbooking', 
            data: serializedData,
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);          
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "Posting failed." );

        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

http://www.example.com/booking/checkbooking:

```
public function checkbooking(){
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

I cant get any post value. What have I miss?

Comment: provide pls full html code

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим, This is all my full. the rest is just around 50 to 60  input checkbox. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no element like $form, use $('#class-form') instead of $form.

```
<form class="form-book" id="class-form" method="POST">
  inside full of checkbox....
<button type="button" class="btn" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-btn').click(function(){  
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");
                var serializedData = $('#class-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.example.com/booking/checkbooking', 
            data: serializedData,
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);          
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "Posting failed." );

        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually is works. It been so many year never touch checkbox. I forget it will not post if never checked.....lol.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use `method: 'POST'` not `type: 'POST'` if you're using a jQuery version larger than 1.9.0

If `$_POST` is empty, you're either not POSTING it, or it's being emptied and handled elsewhere for security.

You could also check the HTTP Headers and ensure the POST data is actually being sent, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome) for instructions

> type (default: 'GET') Type: String An alias for method. You should use
>   type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

An alias for method.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/booking/checkbooking', 
    data: $('form#class-form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
            // stuff to do before ajax request is made
    },
    success: function (data) {
            // same as .done()
    },
    error: function() {
            // same as .fail()
    }
});
```

Comment: Give us some descriptions, why not type but method?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ type (default: 'GET') Type: String
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @СеменихинМаксим - updated answer

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим, my js is {js('jquery-1.10.min.js',$attr,TRUE)}