# Avoiding "forced use" of Microsoft Outlook client

Tags: email, outlook, calendar, imap, postfix-mta

The company where I work heavily uses Microsoft products.  As a Linux user, I usually find a way around the official guidelines (in an above-board and legal way).  The ICT support typically isn't much use, but I usually manage nicely.

The latest thing is now that, later this month, we will only be able to use Microsoft Outlook as an email and calendar client.

My first question is: what does this entail, or how does this work, or how is this enforced?  Is it a kind of user-agent string that needs to match when connecting over e.g. IMAP and SMTP?  Is it Windows 10 that will only allow the Outlook client for email?  Or is something more complex going on?  Currently, I'm not even sure where to start looking...

My second question is, of course: is there a way to circumvent this?  Can I pretend to be Outlook somehow (similar to [wget pretending to be Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182879/using-wget-to-fake-browser))?  Both OfflineImap and postfix are open-source code, so how could I extend those programs to do this?  Or is no programming necessary, since there is an existing solution?  Email forwarding from the server isn't an option.

In case this is useful, I'm using Gentoo Linux, currently with offlineimap to fetch mail from `outlook.office365.com` and store it locally in Maildir format, postfix to send it to `smtp.office365.com`, and mu and mu4e in emacs to read and write.  My system nicely integrates with nine other email accounts, local filtering, my orgmode agenda/todo, git repos, GitHub, and whatever I want really, and I'd loathe to give it all up (in particular the flexibility and emacs key strokes).  The Gentoo bit means that I can easily patch a package before I compile and install it.

Comment: Office365 will be enforcing OAUTH login for IMAP soon, and tools will have to grow to understand that. This is theoretically surmountable, some have gotten gmail integration.  But also, your IT department can restrict which Oauth clients are used or turn off IMAP all together.  Outlook does not use IMAP natively; I’ve heard evolution can speak some of the special protocols (EAS, EWS),  but I’m not sure there exists something like offlineimap that does.

Comment: Firstly, this is not a programming question, and secondly (not to sound too obnoxious)  instead of dismissing Outlook out of hand, try to use it - be open minded and you'll actually enjoy it.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Could you help me how to extend the OfflineImap so that it works with Office365?  Also, could you help me to the download site for Outlook for Linux?  I haven't been able to trace a copy.  I'd like to know to which extent Emacs key bindings are supported, or whether I need to implement them myself (that will be easier than retraining my fingers after 20 years).  Interestingly, the "open-mindedness" of our company to find that Microsoft offers the best solution for *any* situation is something I'm trying to improve here by not dismissing all the other solutions out of hand.

Comment: @AstroFloyd The support for OAuth for IMAP was announced less than a week ago.  I'm not sure anyone has managed to get it working right just yet (see recent questions on [imap]).

Comment: @Max Thank you for this info!  As I said, I'm not even sure where to look, so any info is appreciated :-)