# RoR How to access multiple model params posted through the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a simple form with Ruby on Rails to submit an order.

My form needs to submit information from 3 different models: the user, the catalog_item and the order itself.

Here's my order model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    after_initialize :default_values
    validates :quantity, presence: true

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :catalog_item
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :catalog_item_id, presence: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
    validates_associated :user
end
```

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :orders
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

def checkout
    @order = Order.new(catalog_item: CatalogItem.find(params[:catalog_item_id]), user: User.new)
end

def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
        # redirect_to confirmation_path
    else
        # redirect_to error_path
    end
end

private
    def user_params
    [:name, :email, :phone_number]
  end

    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:id, :catalog_item_id, user_attributes: user_params)
    end
end
```

And here is my view form:

```
<%= form_for @order do |order_form| %>
    <%= order_form.hidden_field :catalog_item_id %>
    <%= order_form.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
        <%= user_fields.label :name %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :name %>
    <%= user_fields.label :email %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :email %>
    <%= user_fields.label :phone_number %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :phone_number %>
    <% end %>
    <%= order_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This if the form HTML:

```
<form class="new_order" id="new_order" action="/orders" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+z8JfieTzJrNgsr99C4jwBtXqIrpNtiEGPdVi73qJrpiGPpjYzbLwUng+e+yp8nIS/TLODWVFQtZqS/45SUoJQ==">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="order[catalog_item_id]" id="order_catalog_item_id">
    <label for="order_user_attributes_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="order[user_attributes][name]" id="order_user_attributes_name">
    <label for="order_user_attributes_email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="order[user_attributes][email]" id="order_user_attributes_email">
    <label for="order_user_attributes_phone_number">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="order[user_attributes][phone_number]" id="order_user_attributes_phone_number">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Order" data-disable-with="Create Order">
```

Here are my routes:

```
get 'checkout/:catalog_item_id', to: 'orders#checkout', as: 'checkout'
post 'orders', to: 'orders#create'
```

When I try to save the `@order` inside the action `create` I get this error:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe95d58b698 @base=#<Order id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, catalog_item_id: 1>, @messages={:user_id=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:user_id=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

However it does work if I do this:

```
@catalog_item = CatalogItem.find(order_params[:catalog_item_id])
@user = User.new(order_params[:user_attributes])
@user.save
@order = Order.new(catalog_item: @catalog_item, user: @user)
```

This is what is being sent in the HTTP request when I post the form:

```
order[catalog_item_id]:1
order[user_attributes][name]:Ana
order[user_attributes][email]:ana@gmail.com
order[user_attributes][phone_number]:123123123
commit:Create Order
```

I am new to RoR and I don't understand why order_params doesn't have the user but it does have the catalog_item_id.

Any help will be truly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What view have you posted? Log the params hash and you'll see what the form is actually passing. Any data that you need for the method that is not collected by the form, you can pass in a hidden field.

Comment: @margo When I log the params this is what I get `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9tXNW6m8fDha53/HGL1i+yTzDEDDsHbcx87KpqugI0dv8j5G7Rl7Y96FTNVeNIjzdFBv8h8Tu1OGkLDV828t2A==", "user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"John", "email"=>"john@example.com", "phone_number"=>"123123123"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Create Order", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>` I posted the form from the checkout view `get 'checkout/:catalog_item_id', to: 'orders#checkout', as: 'checkout'`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to the actual scenario - can an order only ever have one item?

Comment: @max Yes that's correct. The idea is that the app will allow people to order workshops (catalog_items), but it's a simple workflow in that the user comes into the website, chooses the workshop and checksout. So only one catalog_item per order. No need to login either.

Comment: Yeah then definatly make it a nested route.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `Order` model `belongs_to :user`, My "suggested-rails-best-practice" solution is as follows:

See [Rails Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for more info. Basically what Nested Attributes does is it allows you to "create" also an associated record (in your example, the associated User) in just one command:

```
# example code:
Order.create(
  catalog_item_id: 1,
  user_attributes: {
    name: 'Foo',
    email: 'foo@bar.com'
  }
)

# above will create two records (i.e.):
# 1) <Order id: 1 catalog_item_id: 1>
# 2) <User id: 1, order_id: 1, name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@bar.com'>
```

Now that you can also pass in `user_attributes` as part of the hash when creating an order, it's easy enough to just treat `user_attributes` as also part of the request params, see `controller` below.

#### Model:

```
# app/models/order.rb
belongs_to :user

accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

# from our discussion, the validation needs to be updated into:
validates :user, presence: true
validates :category_item, presence: true
```

#### Controller:

```
# app/controllers/orders_controller.rb

def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)

  if @order.save
    # DO SOMETHING WHEN SAVED SUCCESSFULLY
  else
    # DO SOMETHING WHEN SAVING FAILED (i.e. when validation errors)
    render :checkout
  end
end

private

# "Rails Strong Params" see for more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:id, :catalog_item_id, user_attributes: [:name, :email, :phone_number])
end
```

#### View;

```
<%= form_for @order do |order_form| %>
  <!-- YOU NEED TO PASS IN catalog_item_id as a hidden field so that when the form is submitted the :catalog_item_id having the value pre-set on your `checkout` action, will be also submitted as part of the request -->
  <%= order_form.hidden_field :catalog_item_id %>

  <%= order_form.fields_for :user do |user_form| %>
    <%= user_form.label :name %>
    <%= user_form.text_field :name %>
    <%= user_form.label :email %>
    <%= user_form.text_field :email %>
    <%= user_form.label :phone_number %>
    <%= user_form.text_field :phone_number %>
    <% end %>
  <%= order_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your help! This is making a lot of sense to me. :-) I have made the changes in my application as suggested, however when I try to save the order it gets rolled back due to `#<Enumerator: ["User must exist", "User can't be blank"]:each>`. I checked the order_params which is missing the user for some reason `<ActionController::Parameters {"catalog_item_id"=>"1"} permitted: true>`. In my Order model I have `belongs_to`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `validates_associated` for `:user`. I also have `validates :user_id, presence: true`. Would this be causing a problem? Ta!

Comment: @Ana hi Ana, did you implement also my "Strong-Params" above? `params.require(:order).permit(:id, :catalog_item_id, user_attributes: [:name, :email, :phone_number])` ? Also, did you change yours into this specifically `<%= order_form.fields_for :user do |user_form| %>` from above? That is important as well, because this line nests the fields from `order` --to--> `user`.

Comment: your current code is `<%= fields_for :user, @order.user do |user_fields| %>` that will generate request params like `user: {name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@bar.com'}`. However, you do not want this. Try changing it into `<%= order_form.fields_for :user do |user_form| %>`. You'll notice that the request params becomes something like `order: { user_attributes: { name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@bar.com' }}`. See the difference? The other one is nested, while the other is not. If you have read my answer above,you'll immediately realize why this nested one will work when the params are passed into `Order.create`

Comment: @Ana if this still doesn't work, can you update your question, and add the HTML of the form on the page? If you don't know how to do this and you're using Chrome, see [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/). Furthermore, can you also add to your question details about the request? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome) Basically, what I'd like to see is the request params. When you already have your Chrome Dev Tools opened, submit your form, then copy the request params.

Comment: Hi Jay, I haven't had a chance to do this yet, but I will do it later today and post the outcome. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hi Jay, I checked my form and I had changed the code to `<%= order_form.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %> to make sure it is nested. I still get an empty user. I updated my code above. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Did you add this line? `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` in the `Order` model as I have written above?

Comment: Hi Jay, yes I have. I have added the info you requested above (HTTP request, HTML form) and also included the Order controller. I am sure it's a small thing that I am not seeing.

Comment: Hmm that's strange... I wonder if your `after_initialize :default_values` overrides the `User` value. Can you also show the code for `default_values`?

Comment: The code is `def default_values self.quantity ||= 1 end`

Comment: Your request params looks ok, and everything seems to be ok. Can you run this in the action method? `order = Order.new(catalog_item_id: 99, user_attributes: {name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@example.com'}) \n puts order.user`? And let me know the results? \n means newline by the way

Comment: Hi Jay, I did that and after `puts @order.user` I logged `@order` and got `#<Order id: nil, quantity: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, catalog_item_id: 99>`. Then I tried to save the `@order` and the transaction got rolled back. It seems like saving the `@order` is not propagating saving the `@user`. Do I have to indicate that somehow in the User model?

Comment: What does `puts @order.user` show in the Rails server? Or you can just log it actually so `logger.debug(@order.user)` instead of `puts @order.user` if you're unfamiliar with `puts`

Comment: Sure. This is what it logs `#<User id: nil, name: "Foo", email: "foo@example.com", phone_number: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`. I got all my code on github if that's not too much trouble.

Comment: @Ana seems like the `user` is associated to the new `order` just fine as you can see above

Comment: Yes correct. Same when I do this `@catalog_item = CatalogItem.find(order_params[:catalog_item_id]) \n
@user = User.new(order_params[:user_attributes]) \n @user.save \n @order = Order.new(catalog_item: @catalog_item, user: @user) \n @order.save`. It just doesn't work with `@order = Order.new(order_params) \n @order.save` which seems like the cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Oh I think it's the validation. Can you update your code into `validates :user, presence: true` and `validates :category_item, presence: true`? You usually (except in some cases) validate association this way, instead of validating the actual `_id` attribute.

Comment: Although, I doubt this would have an effect as yours was validated without errors even if the user_id is still blank at the start. But just in case this, can you try changing with the above code.

Comment: Sure will do. What's the `:category`?

Comment: If this still doesn't work. I can try checking out your github repo, and debug on this myself as I am curious as well why it doesn't work :)

Comment: Sure, it is okay to post github repo in here?

Comment: I don't have any other ideas haha :) Can you share me your github repo? I'll try to debug.

Comment: Yes, it's fine :)

Comment: Okay it's this one https://github.com/anahenneberke/worklife. This app is just for learning so the code is not that clean (yet!). :-)

Comment: hey no worries! Give me a few minutes. I'll be back.

Comment: Seems like it works when I changed it into `validates :user, presence: true` and `validates :category_item, presence: true` Can you try again?

Comment: actually maybe I'll submit a pull request then, so you could pull my updated code.

Comment: Do you mean `:catalog_item`? If I use `:category_item` I get `undefined method 'category_item'`. I'll wait for the pull request, probably be easier that way.

Comment: The problem was the `validates :catalog_item_id, presence: true` should have been `validates :catalog_item, presence: true` as you said. I cannot thank you enough! Should I post the solution as an answer in this page?

Comment: I just submitted a pull request. Glad it worked! :) I'll update my answer, so you won't need to write the solution.

Comment: Thank you so SO much Jay-Ar! I have learned a lot during this Q&A, including debugging the application. :-)

Comment: No worries! :) By the way, another cool trick on debugging is to make use of `byebug`. Just insert that on aaaaaany part of a ruby file. That will pause the execution, and once paused, you'll be able to inspect variables, update variables, create new variables, etc... as if you are running the code in that specific line where you insert `byebug`. Press `c` and press Enter to unpause. This is very helpful!!! You'll appreciate it surely! :)

Comment: Great I will do. So glad I will be able to move on now and keep building this app. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Good luck further ahead. Let me know if you get stuck :) Hopefully I could help

Answer (score 0):

User is a class so `fields_for :user` creates fields for a new user object.

Try calling `order_form.fields_for` instead of `fields_for` to scope the fields_for to your order object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to create orders from the show view for an item you can setup a nested route instead:

```
resources :catalog_items do 
  resources :orders, only: [:create]
end
```

Make sure you have

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :catalog_item_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  validates_associated :user # triggers user validations
end

class CatalogItem
  has_many :orders
end
```

Then you can do:

```
# /app/views/orders/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for [@catalog_item, @order || @catalog_item.orders.new] do |order_form| %>
  <%= order_form.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
    <%= user_fields.label :name %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :name %>
    <%= user_fields.label :email %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :email %>
    <%= user_fields.label :phone_number %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :phone_number %>
  <% end %>
  <%= order_form.submit %>
<% end %>

# /app/views/catalog_items/show 
<%= render partial: 'orders/form' %>
```

This will set the form url to `/catalog_items/:catalog_item_id/orders`. which means that we pass `catalog_item_id` through the URL and not the form params -
 - this is a better practice as it makes the route descriptive and RESTful.

Then setup the controller:

```
class OrderController
  # POST /catalog_items/:catalog_item_id/orders
  def create
    @catalog_item = CatalogItem.find(params[:catalog_item_id])
    @order = @catalog_item.orders.new(order_params)
    # Uncomment the next line if you have some sort of authentication like Devise 
    # @order.user = current_user if user_signed_in?
    if @order.save
      redirect_to @catalog_item, success: 'Thank you for your order'
    else
      render 'catalog_items/show' # render show view with errors.
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

  def user_params
    [:name, :email, :phone_number]
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order)
          .permit(:id, user_attributes: user_params)
  end
end
```

Comment: You're making another very common noob misstake - always call `save` and `update` with an `if` statement and respond to success and failure.

Comment: You should also setup the routes with `resources :orders`

Comment: Thanks @max I am going to give this a go. I was hoping to make the catalog_item_id field hidden.

Comment: Edited. Making the route nested might be what you actually are looking for.

Comment: I think I am getting closer. I am sending the catalog_id as a hidden field but I will change it to the nested route you purposed later. I managed to get what I need in the params `<ActionController::Parameters {"catalog_item_id"=>"1", "user_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Ana Henneberke", "email"=>"ana.henneberke4@gmail.com", "phone_number"=>"07501782993"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>` but when I try to save the order `@order = Order.new(order_params) @order.save` I get this error `#<Enumerator: ["User can't be blank"]:each>`.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and check `@order.user.errors` the user is not being saved for some reason and I'm to tired to figure it out.

Comment: It works when I save the user first and then the order `@catalog_item = CatalogItem.find(order_params[:catalog_item_id]) @user = User.new(order_params[:user_attributes]) @user.save @order = Order.new(catalog_item: @catalog_item, user: @user) @order.save` (not catching success or failure just to illustrate) so there's something missing somewhere. If I find a solution, I'll post it here. Thanks for your help and patience. :-)

Comment: hmm, then its something with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - I can't really see anything wrong though - but you might want read through the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html