# Heroku Amazon s3 images - 403 error sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403

I have my server setup at Heroku and i've used Amazon s3 for image-storage (uploaded them with the [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)), but sometimes i get strange 403 errors:

**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"**

### (See image below)

[image: Image of my webpage with missing images]

---

If i reload the page the images are shown again.

I've set up a CORSRule:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>Accept-Ranges</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Range</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Encoding</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Range</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```

I'm not an expert with CORSRule and i tried a few, but i would be so happy if anyone could point me in the right direction.

#### --------------- Updated --------------

Here i have my Request General, Response Headers and Request Headers when i'm missing an image.

#### General

```
Request URL:https://exnerbilleder.s3.amazonaws.com/nye/uploads/image/image/215/thumb_5.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:52.95.150.17:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

#### Response Headers

```
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Tue, 08 Aug 2017 15:49:49 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
x-amz-id-2:EG4D5X29x8eAuu+xD9PdG2MsdGYnWHnpkuOc87p1h7nbFgvk57S6Be631UwTdF9tHMauoAjf6j4=
x-amz-request-id:0C43705C41CD57C9
```

#### Request Headers

```
Accept:image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:exnerbilleder.s3.amazonaws.com
Referer:http://inger-exner.herokuapp.com/works/slotsgarden
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

---

#### Visit site

Maybe you will experience the problem if you visit [the site](http://inger-exner.herokuapp.com/vaerker/kirker-og-sognegarde)

Comment: More detail is needed.  The request and response headers from the failed requests, in particular.

Comment: Okay. Do you know where i can find them? Is it on the Amazon page?

Comment: In the browser's developer tools.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423097/1695906

Comment: I have updated the answer. :)

Comment: Look at the response in the browser tools, this gives the error <Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code><Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message> - so looks like there is a problem with permissions on the s3 side.

Comment: I've bought some Amazon support and are know waiting. I will return when i know more.

Comment: I wrote the Amazon support and they answered: **The root cause of this issue was an error that caused a small number of the authenticating and authorizing service hosts to miss changes applied to your account.** 
They pushed the subscription data updates to all the service hosts and that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @PeterAndersen glad it got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an Amazon issue. A tool such as New Relic or Skylight can help you debug this type of problem where different components lying on different service providers are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

You can refer to the two links below for help :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails