# How does this URL respond with either an image or a webpage embedding that image?

Tags: html, .htaccess, web-services, http, webserver

The url for [this gif of Michael Jackson eating Tide Pods](https://media1.tenor.com/images/f1fec382c29ce096bfbacd7844c54e0f/tenor.gif) has some interesting behavior I haven't seen before. I'm an avid internet user but my knowledge of HTTP is limited. I know that a webserver can respond however it wants to a request and provide metadata to help a browser figure out what sort of content it actually responded with, so it's not too surprising that a `.gif` url could actually return a something other than a `.gif` and be correctly displayed. What confuses me is how the webpage generated by the `.gif` url contains itself in an `img` tag.

Is this just some sort of opaque server-side magic? (i.e. server is using HTTP request header to guess if the request is coming from a URL in a `<img>` or a browser address bar)

Comment: Pretty much that last sentence, yes. Compare the two HTTP requests in your browser…

Comment: This question on how to view those headers is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Comment: For anyone as clueless as me, in the chrome inspector, under Network, "tenor.gif" corresponds to both the webpage and the image. It shows both requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, what seems to make a difference is the presence of `text/html` in `accept:` header.

Try:

```
curl 'https://media1.tenor.com/images/f1fec382c29ce096bfbacd7844c54e0f/tenor.gif' \
-H 'accept: text/html'
```

then try:

```
curl 'https://media1.tenor.com/images/f1fec382c29ce096bfbacd7844c54e0f/tenor.gif' \
-H 'accept: */*'
```

[List of default Accept values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values#Values_for_an_image)

> When requesting an image, like through an HTML `<img>` element,
>   user-agent often sets a specific list of media types to be welcomed:

```
|User Agent|Value                       |
-----------------------------------------
|Firefox   |*/* (since Firefox 47)      |
|Safari    |*/*                         |
|Chrome    |image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8|
```