# click html button no onclick/link

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to automate a task with python. This task is simply to open a link, put some text into the field and click the button. I can't seem to figure out where the link is for this button/how to click this button through python or a different programming language. I dont see an onclick() or ref/link for it. When I get the html code for the site the button is not in it but when I inspect the elements of the page I can see it. Please let me know what I should do thanks in advance. [webpage_elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIUiR.png)

Comment: You should probably just hit the API directly instead of trying to use web automation. Can you see the network request when you perform the action yourself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can I go about seeing the network request when I perform the action myself?

Comment: You don't have a button because it needs javascript to render. You need to use real browser. Use playwright https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro. Also add URL page to your post.

Comment: @ZackPaquette you can see request here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/how-can-i-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Comment: @MeT playwright did it. Thank you so much!!!!! Why did playwright do it and not selenium? Is there a way to obtain the source/element code from after the javascript is processed? I could not post the link bc it is work related unfortunately.