# Avoid download of previously downloaded files using Java FTP

Tags: java, ftp

I have a desktop application which downloads all files on server.When a new file is added I want to download only the newer file.

Answer (score 0):

Well to know which one is the "new one" you have to create a map/or other datastructure and put pair of the name/metadata creationtime(or last modified time)which one suits you best , when you iterate over your files just see their metadata with

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

 attr.creationTime(); //or attr.lastModifiedTime();
```

When you compare these times with one on server decide to download only the one  with latest time.

Either way you have to keep track of at least the name/time modified(or created) at your previous download and compare these.

If this application on your desktop is not some kind of service that runs nonstop,find some way to persist that data on system,serialization or embed database h2/hsqldb within it.Use streams with conncurent iteration/ parralelStream to check these times and compare ,in case you use java8

edit- to get metadata from url, check this question [Get the Last Modified date of an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999258/get-the-last-modified-date-of-an-url)